# How to reference a dynamic range in Google Sheets Script?

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script, formulas, google-sheets-named-ranges

I have a sheet where the filter originally started on row 2, so my range was `A2:J`. As I've added and deleted rows/columns, my range has changed and it's still changing as I edit the sheet.

Is there a way to name a dynamic range so that if I add/delete columns, my functions will work properly? Kind of like how Sheets/Excel will update formulas if a cell reference is edited.

I have `sort by` and `set cursor at cell` functions that run `onOpen`. However, if I don't manually update the range, then everything gets screwed up every time I open the document. For instance, a few days ago my range was `"A6:J" + lr`; my filter was on row 6. I added another header row, making my filter row 7, but the script referenced `A6` as the range to sort. This screwed up my data. It's driving me nuts!

Would appreciate some insight on how to reference a dynamic range. Not sure if `INDIRECT` or `ADDRESS` would work?? Not sure if [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29975801/update-named-range-automatically) makes sense?

```
 function onOpen(){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("DATA");
  var lastRow = ss.getLastRow();
  var lastColumn = ss.getLastColumn();
  var lastCell = ss.getRange(lastRow, lastColumn);
  var range = ss.getRange("A7:" + lastRow);
  Logger.log(ss.getRange(lastRow, lastColumn).getDataRegion().getA1Notation());
  var columnToSortBy = 2;
  var range = ss.getRange("A7:J" + lr);
  range.sort( { column : columnToSortBy, ascending: true } );
  var r = Math.max.apply(Math, ss.getRange('B:B').getValues()
        .map(function (d, i) {
            if (d[0]) return i + 1;
        }).filter(function (d) {
            return d;
        })) + 1;
    ss.setActiveRange(ss.getRange(r, 2))
}
```

---

### EDIT: I figured it out! Answer below

Combine `.getFrozenRows()+1` with `lastRow` and `lastColumn` to get a dynamic range that begins after a header row. If a column/row is added/deleted, the range referenced in the function will automatically update. This only works for ranges that begin after a header/filter row, and end with the last filled column.

You can run a log to see if this matches the target range. Run the log below, view log. Then add a row or column, re-run log and compare:

```
var range = ss.getRange(ss.getFrozenRows()+1, 1, ss.getLastRow(), ss.getLastColumn());
Logger.log("Sorting Range: %s", range.getA1Notation());
```

StackExchange has provided so many answers for me, so I hope this helps somebody else :) Full explanation with more test logs below.

Comment: i think i figured it out!

Comment: Thank you :) ducks.

Answer (score 2):

I think I figured it out! Using `getFrozenRows()` gives me all rows up to the filter. If I add `getFrozenRows()+1` then I get the first cell of the range I want to sort (excludes the header rows). I can combine that with `lastRow` to get the dynamic range.

I changed `var range` to `var range = ss.getRange(ss.getFrozenRows()+1, 1, ss.getLastRow(), ss.getLastColumn());`
Only issue is that it gives the last filled row + 6. Example, lastRow is M318, but the log shows M324. I've tried it on other sheets, for some reason it always adds 6 rows. I've tried it on a test sheet that i filled and using the new range works great.

A workaround is to run a function to remove any rows without data. My function also includes deleting empty columns. Caveat: sheet cannot be empty. Must have at least one cell with data

`function removeEmptyRowsColumns(){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  var maxRows = ss.getMaxRows(); 
  var lastRow = ss.getLastRow();
  var maxColumns = ss.getMaxColumns();
  var lastColumn = ss.getLastColumn();
  ss.deleteRows(lastRow+1, maxRows-lastRow);
  ss.deleteColumns(lastColumn+1, maxColumns-lastColumn);
}`

Here's what the final function looks like:

`function sortColumn(){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  var range = ss.getRange(ss.getFrozenRows()+1, 1, ss.getLastRow(), ss.getLastColumn());
  Logger.log(ss.getRange(lastRow, lastColumn).getDataRegion().getA1Notation());
  var columnToSortBy = 2;
  range.sort( { column : columnToSortBy, ascending: true } );
  var r = Math.max.apply(Math, ss.getRange('B:B').getValues()
        .map(function (d, i) {
            if (d[0]) return i + 1;
        }).filter(function (d) {
            return d;
        })) + 1;
    ss.setActiveRange(ss.getRange(r, 2))
}`

I had to go through a ton of trial and error to figure out the dynamic range. I found it helpful to run some logs. You can run a test logs function, or add the `Logger.log()` to your function to see if the result matches your target range. I compiled some of the logs I ran into a function to make it easier for me to compare

`function testLogs(){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("ENTER SHEET NAME");
  var lastRow = ss.getLastRow()+1;
  var lastColumn = ss.getLastColumn();
  var lastCell = ss.getRange(lastRow, lastColumn);
  var maxRows = ss.getMaxRows(); 
  var maxColumns = ss.getMaxColumns()
  var range = ss.getActiveRange();
  var dataRange = ss.getRange(ss.getFrozenRows()+1, 1, ss.getMaxRows(), ss.getMaxColumns());
  var newRange = ss.getRange(ss.getFrozenRows()+1, 1, ss.getLastRow(), ss.getLastColumn());
  Logger.log("ACTUAL Sorting Range: %s", newRange.getA1Notation());          // result: full range, starting after filter row
  Logger.log("# frozen rows: %s", ss.getFrozenRows());                       // result: # frozen rows (row # = header/filter row)
  Logger.log("sorted data end cell: %s", lastCell.getA1Notation());          // result: range end cell, using last filled column/row (in A1 notation)
  Logger.log("Last Row #: %s", lastRow);                                     // result: last filled row #
  Logger.log("Last Column #: %s", lastColumn);                               // result: last filled column #
  Logger.log("last cell's value: %s", lastCell.getValue());                  // result: last row's, last cell's VALUE
  Logger.log("Sorting Range, incl empty: %s", dataRange.getA1Notation());    // result: sorting range, starting after filter row
  Logger.log("last empty row #: %s", maxRows);                               // result: last empty row # 
  Logger.log("last empty column #: %s", maxColumns);                         // result: last empty column #
  Logger.log("cursor end cell: %s", range.getA1Notation());                  // result: range end cell, depending on cursor locale
}`